# How to get most recent data from table? Laravel 5.5, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, token, mysql-workbench

I have this simple function to get the token of a user.

However, if a user has just been added, I'd need to refresh data in MySQL Workbench before the code can pull it via code which would be a problem on production.

```
public function getToken($user_id) {
    $token = \DB::table('social_providers')->where('user_id', $user_id)->value('token');
    return $token;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset.
If your table has `created_at` column you can use this

```
$token = \DB::table('social_providers')
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->latest()
    ->value('token');
```

otherwise

```
$token = \DB::table('social_providers')
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->orderByDesc('id') // or ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->value('token');
```

where `id` is primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
->order_by('datetime', 'desc')
->limit(1);
```

use this proper ans.